# Add a column in a entity without deleting the data

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am new to symfony.
(Sorry for my bad English, I don't speak English).

I use Doctrine, I have a user entity with these fields: name, first name

I would like to add an email field.

Make :

```html
php bin / console make: entity user
...
php bin / console d: m:m
```

delete all the data I have in the database, how do I add the email column without deleting the content?

thank you in advance for your help

Seb

Comment: [Doctrine Migrations](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-migrations/en/3.0/index.html)

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#migrations-adding-more-fields

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the field to your existing entity and then execute `php bin/console d:s:u -f`

To add the new field in your entity, it depends if you use annotation or yaml or xml.

To execute the command, it also depends on your symfony version. see the doc https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html#executing-the-command